# How to integrate theme from html to magento

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, integration

How to make custom theme in magento from html pages like as i have html theme. I want to integrate html to magento.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is expecting a much too large answer. Magento theme development is a pretty complex matter and there are literally books written on the topic, you can get started with a tutorial like [this one](http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-a-new-magento-theme/) but eventually you should probably purchase a book if you really want to get going quick, as there are not that many good online resources on the matter.

Many Magento 1 books are getting a bit older, but they will still largely be valid for Magento 1.9. Suggestions would be Alan Storm's "No Frills Magento Layout" (which covers a lot) and Richard Carter's "Magento 1.4 Themes Design".